# AWS Sagemaker Unable to Parse Augmented Manifest File

Tags: python, json, amazon-web-services, machine-learning, amazon-sagemaker

I've read all of the existing documentation on Augmented Manifest files. I see no difference from my file, but I keep experiencing this error when training:

```
ClientError: Data download failed:Failed to download data. Unable to parse augmented manifest, error in line: 1
```

My example first line:

```
{"source-ref": "s3://test-bucket/test-data/test/bucket/10done.png", "video-frame-object-detection": {"annotations": [{"class_id": 1, "top": 880, "left": 43, "width": 2499, "height": 324}], "image_size": [{"width": 2543, "height": 2543, "depth": 3}]}, "video-frame-object-detection-metadata": {"class-map": {"0": "Good", "1": "Bad"}, "human-annotated": "no", "creation-date": "2022-06-09T11:01:27.440682", "type": "programmatically-created-labels"}}
```

These are how my breaks look (end of file):

[image: ![enter image description here]

How I manually created the manifest file:
[image: ![enter image description here]

Sagemaker is recognizing my attributes as well.

Answer (score 0):

The error is clearly coming from the syntax error from your Augment manifest files. It should be in jsonlines format. Can you check with some gener

Comment: It passes all JSON line tests.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the JSON Line page https://jsonlines.org/
Point 3 in there says

> 3. Line Separator is '\n' This means '\r\n' is also supported because surrounding white space is implicitly ignored when parsing JSON
>    values.
>
> The last character in the file may be a line separator, and it will be
> treated the same as if there was no line separator present.

Your output shows CRLF as end of line markers and JSON lines format says it should just be LF